# Object was not declared in scope (std::map)

Tags: c++

I have a class with a map called students where I would like to store instances of another class. I get the following error message:

‘Student’ was not declared in this scope

```
std::map<int, Student> students;
```

Here is the relevant part of my code:

APP.H

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "student.h"

class App
{
public:
    void AddStudent();

protected:
    std::string SName;
    std::string SEmail;

    std::map<int, Student> students;
};
```

APP.CPP

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "app.h"
#include "student.h"

void App::AddStudent()
{
    std::cin >> SName;
    std::cin >> SEmail;
    Student Stu(SName, SEmail);
    students.insert(std::make_pair(someID, Stu));
}
```

STUDENT.H

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "app.h"
#include "test.h"

class Student
{
public:
    Student() { }
    Student(std::string studentName, std::string studentEmail);
    int studentId;

    std::string GetStudentName() const;
    std::string GetStudentEmail() const;
    void SetStudentName(std::string sn);
    void SetStudentEmail(std::string se);

private:
    static int tempId;

    std::string studentName;
    std::string studentEmail;
};
```

If I copy my map to main, I don't receive this error, but then I can't access it when I try to insert the instance. I'd rather not have this map in main.

Comment: Where is `Student` defined?

Comment: Can you provide `student.h` too?

Comment: Student is a separate class, takes in two std::string parameters, these are stored in private variables with setters and getters. I didn't want to copy all that code in here.

Comment: @BlackMoses I am not able to build, doesn't matter if I declare Student Stu in cpp or not.

Comment: No need to include `student.h` in `app.cpp`, it already gets it via the inclusion of `app.h`. Also, what is the need of including `app.h` in `student.h`?

Comment: @CinCout Thank you, that was it! I deleted the unnecessary includes and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

`student.h` includes `app.h`, but `app.h` includes `student.h`.

In your case, you can just remove the `#include "app.h"` from `student.h`, because it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment as an answer:

Do the following two things:

1. No need to include `student.h` in `app.cpp`, it already gets it via the inclusion of `app.h`
2. Do not include `app.h` in `student.h`